# Make inference on overall density of duplicate records from a sample

Tags: inference, proportion, sample

I have a file, typically of several million records, for which I need to make an inference on the percent of duplicates (perhaps testing for whether the rate exceeds a certain percent, or just coming up with an estimate and confidence interval, etc.).

A comparison (not computationally trivial) is required to determine whether any two records are duplicates.  (There are other integrity checks I will run, but it is not necessary to use the entire dataset for these.)

So, I would like to try a sampling approach.  Randomize the file of some $n > 1$ observations and select some $m>1$ for comparison (of each record to the other $m-1$ records).

For $n$ observations, we know that there are ${n \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ unordered pairs to check for duplicates.  Within $m$ sampled records, I can check for duplicates among $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ of these pairs,  $\sim \frac{m^2}{n^2}$ of total pairs.

**The question:**  I would like to know how to estimate the mean (and ideally, also the variance) of the proportion of records which have at least one duplicate.  Also, is it necessary to assume that duplicate pairings must be spread out evenly among records, or does the mean still hold if the duplicate pairings are very concentrated within a small set of records?

**My initial attempt** was, if I find $k$ records with at least one duplicate among $m$ sample observations, I would estimate that there are $k /\frac{m^2}{n^2}$ total duplicates out of $n$ records, for a duplicate proportion of $\frac{kn}{m^2}$, but that doesn't work out -- try plugging in `n=100`, `m=10`, `k=1`, which produces a 100% duplicate rate.  I believe that the fallacy is that I am dividing by the proportion of total pairs examined, rather than the proportion of records examined, but I don't think $\frac{k}{m}$ is right either...

Comment: Can records be replicated more than once?  That is, is it possible for there to be triplicates, quadruplicates, etc.?  If so, how are those to be counted?  For instance, is a quadruplicate a single "duplicate" or four duplicates or even $\binom{4}{2}=6$ duplicates?

Comment: @whuber Yes, there could be multiple replicates.  In the case of quadruplicates (4 records resolving to the same entity) I would like to treat that as 3 duplicates and 1 original.  If that was the entire file, I would say that that file is 75% duplicate records.  However, I'm open to some other counting rules if they make the math easier and I can explain them.

Comment: Unless the majority are duplicates, you might need to sample most of the records to obtain a good estimate.  Maybe it would be more fruitful to look more closely at the duplicate-checking algorithm: often there can be huge speedups afforded by changing the algorithm, especially when you can capitalize on information collected with each duplicate check.

Comment: @whuber agreed, my algorithm is terrible... but this question could be of general interest if the identity resolution process is unavoidably expensive -- say, facial matches between different images, or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

**A possible rule of thumb** could be:

If I find $k$ duplicated records inside the $m$ records of the file I have observed, there are another $n - m$ records that these $m$ records could be duplicated on... so we might expect another $\frac{k}{m}(n-m)$ duplicates on these $m$ records (for a sub-total of $k + \frac{k}{m}(n-m)$ duplicate records.

(Imagine an $m * m$ square inside an $n * n$ square; this step estimates the duplicate count of an $m*n$ rectangle based on the $m*m$ density)

Then, for the number of duplicates over all $n$ records, again assuming proportionality, we could solve the equation $\frac{m}{n} = \frac{k + \frac{k}{m}(n-m)}{x}$ and obtain $x = \frac{n}{m}*(k + \frac{k}{m}(n-m))$

(This step estimates the duplicate count of an $n*n$ rectangle based on the estimated $m*n$ duplicate count.  In this case, plugging in `n=100`, `m=10`, `k=1` still gives me 100% duplicate rate... which now sort of makes sense, because the $10*10$ square is 1% the area of the $100*100$ square.)

Comment: I am not at all sure that this answer is good, just tossing it out for consideration.